# What is the default PAGER used by man pages?

Tags: default-programs, manpage, less, more, pager

What is the default `PAGER` used by man pages.

I,e what is the program runs the man pages?

It look some like `more` or `less`. I'm sure it's not `more` since `more` doesn't support reverse backward.

Comment: It looks more or less like `more` (or `less`), I think.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From [`man man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/man.1.html):

```
                                                  ... The pager can  be
specified  in  a number of ways, or else will fall back to a default is
used (see option -P for details). 

...
-P pager, --pager=pager
       Specify  which  output pager to use.  By default, man uses pager
       -s.  This option overrides the $MANPAGER  environment  variable,
       which  in turn overrides the $PAGER environment variable.  It is
       not used in conjunction with -f or -k.
```

`pager` (`/usr/bin/pager`) is set using the [Debian alternatives system](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) (via `/etc/alternatives/pager`), and defaults to `less`.

```
$ update-alternatives --display pager
pager - auto mode
  link currently points to /bin/less
/bin/less - priority 77
  slave pager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/less.1.gz
/bin/more - priority 50
  slave pager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/more.1.gz
/usr/bin/pg - priority 10
  slave pager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/pg.1.gz
/usr/bin/w3m - priority 25
  slave pager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/w3m.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/bin/less'.
```

---

Apparently, this particular default (using a command named `pager`) is a Debian-derivative trait. See [Which systems have 'pager' shortcut/alias?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5404/70524) over on Unix & Linux.

Comment: Thanks.. I'm confused which one to mark as answer. Both were quick with good information and two different methods to check the symlink of pager.

Comment: @NewUSer Toss a coin. :)

Comment: In addition I think you can change this with the `MANPAGER` in the environment.

Comment: @Ron oh, yes. But that variable is not set by default, AFAICT.

Comment: @muru I'm considering yours, you answered first. Eventhough the other answer is perfect

Comment: @NewUSer ah, don't. Pick the best answer, not the earliest.

Comment: @muru both answers are perfect. almost same

Comment: @muru yeah, from `man man` : `-P` overrides `MANPAGER` which overrides `PAGER`

Comment: If once I change the pager then how to back in default?

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal how did you change it?

Comment: @muru actually I don't know for which that was happend because of I have done many [things](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390724/how-to-create-pdf-from-linux-man-pages-so-that-style-is-presereved?answertab=votes#tab-top) at a time.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal in that case, you should post a new question with the output of `env` and `update-alternatives --display pager`, and the effect when you run `man -D <some-manpage>`, and any changes you did that you can remember.

Comment: @muru what does mean by the `priority`?

Comment: From Debian 9.8.0, if you do `man pager` it'll point you to the man page of `less`. That sums it up (Debian-wise).

Answer (score 20):

By default, it's `less`. As explained in `man man`:

> -P pager, --pager=pager
>
> Specify  which  output pager to use.  **By default, man uses pager
>
>   -s**.  This option overrides the $MANPAGER  environment  variable,   which  in turn overrides the $PAGER environment variable.  It is   not
>   used in conjunction with -f or -k.
>
> The value may be a simple command name or a command  with  argu‐
>   ments, and may use shell quoting (backslashes, single quotes, or
>   double quotes).  It may not use pipes to connect  multiple  com‐
>   mands;  if  you  need that, use a wrapper script, which may take   the
>   file to display either as an argument or on standard input.

On Debian-based systems, including Ubuntu, `pager` is a symlink to `less`:

```
$ readlink -f /usr/bin/pager 
/bin/less
```

This means that `man`'s default, `pager -s`, is `less -s`. You can change this by i) using the `-P` option of `man`; ii) setting the `MANPAGER` or `PAGER` environmental variables.

Comment: Thanks.. I'm confused which one to mark as answer. Both were quick with good information and two different methods to check the symlink of pager.

Comment: Sorry Friend I'm considering @muru answer since he was the first to answer.. But I wish I could choose both, you desrve

Comment: @NewUSer don't worry about it. Both Muru and I have enough rep to keep us happy :) Just accept whichever one you feel answers your question better. I assure you that nobody will be offended.

Comment: both of answers are good enough. Thanks for your sportsman soul

Comment: @terdon `readlink -f /usr/bin/pager` shows `/bin/less` but when I run `man` command it opens in `more` pager. why?

Comment: @alhelal because of the MANPAGER or PAGER environment variables, or you have man aliased to include a -P parameter.

Comment: @TheGatorade Now what can I do(e.g.`man -P less` results error)?