# colors of bold section in man pages

Tags: manpage, less, pager

After upgrade to 16.04 I hit the issue with colors of some sections in man pages e.g. color of bold is black and when I read man pages in terminal with black background there is no possibility to see those sections(as their color is black too).

My TERM env is set to xterm-256color.
How I can change color for bold text in man pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man` uses a pager to show its contents, like `less`, `more` or `most`. Ubuntus default pager is `less`, but you can configure that [in the alternatives system](https://askubuntu.com/a/623995/48867). Additionally, you can tell to use another pager on a case by case basis with the `-P` switch

```
man -P more ls
```

or by setting the `PAGER` or `MANPAGER` environment variables

```
export MANPAGER=more
more ls
```

So to solve your color problem, you can either choose a pager whose default color settings suit you better, or you can look into adapting the color settings of pager you want to use. For example, you can use a bunch of environment variables and `termcap` to [configure the use of color in less](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119/colors-in-man-pages/147#147).

Comment: Thank you, export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$(tput bold; tput setaf 7) is what I want

Comment: Also see http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2016-08-15/colorized-man-pages-understood-and-customized