# How to back on default configuration of man command?

Tags: gnome-terminal, manpage

I have executed many commands from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390724/how-to-create-pdf-from-linux-man-pages-so-that-style-is-presereved?answertab=votes#tab-top), installed  [mandoc](http://mandoc.bsd.lv/), those(I guess) or any thing else(which I don't know) have changed my man pages output decoration.

In previous my man pages show SYNOPSIS in bold and all function's name. And outputs text are spread over the terminal window. Now, these features are lost.

**Previous** output of `man malloc` -

[image: previous man page output]

**Current** output of `man malloc` -

[image: current man page output]

Provided that, if I ran `PAGER=less man <man_page_name>` then the function's name are shown in bold but not spread over terminal window.

**Current** output of `PAGER=less man malloc` -

[image: less_man_malloc]

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and provided some commands outputs mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623992/what-is-the-default-pager-used-by-man-pages/623995?noredirect=1#comment1528216_623995)

`$ env` is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25578427/). I provided this in external link as the output is so large.

`$ update-alternatives --display pager`

```
pager - auto mode
  link currently points to /bin/less
/bin/less - priority 77
  slave pager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/less.1.gz
/bin/more - priority 50
  slave pager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/more.1.gz
/usr/bin/pg - priority 10
  slave pager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/pg.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/bin/less'.
```

`$ man -D malloc`

```
man: invalid option -- 'D'
usage: man [-acfhklw] [-C file] [-M path] [-m path] [-S subsection]
   [[-s] section] name ...
```

Now, what can I do so that `man` command works as previous?

Comment: `-D` is a perfectly valid option for `man` on Ubuntu 14.04, so did you install another version of `man`? What does `type -a man` output?

Comment: What is the current value of `$TERM`?

Comment: @muru see [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25579950/).

Comment: @waltinator see the output of `env` provided in my question. `xterm`

Comment: In your `env` dump (would have been nicer as `env | sort`) that your `PATH` is unreasonably long, fix that. `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:...` 1825 chars, 172 dirs, 11 unique.

Comment: Try it in a "naked" bash shell, with no initialization `bash --norc`

Comment: @waltinator I don't understand what do you want to say. Would you explain please?

Comment: @banda-muhammad-al-helal Type the `bash --norc` command, then try your `man` command in that shell. When you're finished, type `exit` or `^D` to exit that shell, and return to your original.

Comment: @waltinator no change  seemed.